# How to write the below proof rigorously for : If $p$ is a boundary point of $S$, then $p$ is a lim point of $S$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> How to write the below proof rigorously for : If $p$ is a boundary point of $S$, then $p$ is a lim point of $S$?

We have: $p$ is a boundary point of $S$ means that $$\forall r\gt 0, \exists a \in S, \exists b\in S^c| a,b\in N_r(p)$$

Now the definition of a limit point is:

$$\color{green}{\forall r\gt 0, \exists a \in S}, \exists b\in S^c| \color{green}{a},b\color{green}{\in N_r(p)}$$
$$\forall r\gt 0, \exists a \in S|a\in N_r(p)$$

So it seems we obtain the necessary result. But I am unsure of how we write this rigorously. E.g. I don't know how one would format this.

---

Notation:

$S^c$ refers to all points in the universe, let's say $X$, not in $S$. E.g. $X\backslash S$

$N_r(p)$ is an $r$ radius neighbourhood around $p$.

Boundary point is simply defined above, it just means that there are always points in *and* out of our set regardless of how small the neighbourhood.

Comment: I do not get your notation, either I am ignorant or there are typos.

Comment: @Harish Sorry if this is abnormal

Comment: @Harish All edited in, sorry about spam, deleting now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of boundary point is correct, but not your definition of limit point. Given a nonempty subset $S$ of some topological space $X$ a point $p\in X$ is a [*limit point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of $S$, if any neighborhood $U$ of $p$ contains a point $s\in S$ **other than** $p$. When $X$ is a metric space then for each limit point $p$ of $S$ one can find an injective sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ on $S$ converging to $p$.

Comment: I see your concern:  $p$ may be the only point in $S$, and it may have infinitely many points of $S^c$ in every neighborhood, and hence is a boundary point. However, it has no other points of $S$ for some neighborhood, and hence isn't a limit point of $S$. Thanks I will think about this

Answer (score 1):

Formally
$$\begin{align}\text{$p$ is boundary point of $S$} &\;\Longrightarrow \forall r\gt 0\, \exists a \in S\, \exists b\in S^c\colon a,b\in N_r(p) \\&\;\Longrightarrow \forall r\gt 0\, \exists a \in S\colon a\in N_r(p)
\\&\;\Longrightarrow \text{$p$ is a limit point of $S$} \end{align}$$
suffices. The proof is really so simple that no further explanation should be necessary.

If you want to be more verbose you could also write out the quantifiers: If $p$ is a boundary point of $S$ then for all $r > 0$ there are $a \in S$, $b \in S^c$ such that $a, b \in N_r(p)$ and therefore for all $r > 0$ there exists $a \in S$ such that $a \in N_r(p)$, hence $p$ is a limit point of $S$. But in the end this contains as much information as the short proof.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty much how I felt

Comment: This does not conform to the definition of limit point.

Comment: I assumed that $p \not \in S$ (as the original poster judging from his definition). How else does this not conform with the definition of a limit point?